# How to make wordpress theme iframe responsive

Tags: theme-development, responsive

I am currently developing a theme and in my theme youtube video embeds and other video embeds are not really responsive. I found so many posts how to make iframe responsive with plugins. But i need to create my theme responsive for video embeds by default without any plugin.

Specially in youtube embeds, the background image is zoomed in and cropped. It doesn't look like in youtube.

Is there any way to make iframes responsive without any plugins?

Answer (score 1):

> After some research, I came across [this article](https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-video/) and ended up with the
> solution below.
>
> ```
> <div style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; padding-top: 25px; height: 0;">
>     <iframe style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" 
>         src="http://slither.io/" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" 
>         scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
>     </iframe>
> </div>
> ```
>
> What this code does is that it set the div’s width to 100%, and then
> make the div’s resolution to always be 16:9 ratio by setting
>
> ```
> padding-bottom: 56.25%;
> ```
>
> Setting the wrapping div’s position to be relative and the iframe’s
> position to be absolute also plays an important role here.
>
> Now the div always responses to the parent container and always keeps
> the resolution ratio at 16:9.
>
> You can change the ratio by changing the `"padding-bottom: 56.25%"` to
> the ratio you want (notice that `56.25/100 == 9/16`).
>
> If you want to make your code more beautiful, you can add a custom CSS
> to your site (by altering the theme’s code files or adding a custom
> Text Widget) as following
>
> ```
> .responsiveWrapper {
>     position: relative;
>     padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
>     padding-top: 25px;
>     height: 0;
> }
> .responsiveWrapper iframe {
>     position: absolute;
>     top: 0;
>     left: 0;
>     width: 100%;
>     height: 100%;
> }
>
> <div class="responsiveWrapper">
>     <iframe src="http://slither.io/" frameborder="0" 
>         scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
>     </iframe>
> </div>
> ```

Source:
https://hexadix.com/tag/slither-io/

Comment: This answer is copied verbatim from [hexadix.com](https://hexadix.com/tag/slither-io/), which references another article at [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-video/). It might be OK to copy _snippets_ from other sites (providing they are correctly "quoted"), but you must first check the source license and you MUST attribute your sources.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But what about FitwidJs. I found that recently and it seems to be done this in much better way. since it is a JQuery plugin it can enqueued to the theme to work without using it as a normal wordpress plugin. I don't know is this against to wordpress coding standards.